# What are some good Mobile Frameworks/SDKs that are web compliant?

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile

So far I've found the following jQuery/Javascript libraries for mobile development.

- PhoneGap
- appMobi{!}
- jQuery Mobile
- Sencha Touch

I'm wondering what others are available for development that cover the main phones (i.e. Windows Phone 7, Android, and iPhone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried pretty much all of the frameworks out there for pure HTML5, JavaScript, CSS-based development.  Sencha creates wonderful websites, but the learning curve is astounding.  It is one of the most counter-intuitive development tools I have ever used.  I highly recommend that you avoid it. jQuery mobile so far is the best.  It is now in alpha, but generally stable and certainly likely to be the standard approach for targeting mobile in the near future based on its architecture, simplicity, and compatibility.  I look at Phonegap as simply a container for your app or a good library for simplified access to native mobile features; it augments jQuery Mobile and does not replace it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if these support Phone 7 but here are a couple more cross-platform solutions that we evaluated.

Titanium Mobile - http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development
 - like PhoneGap in that it produces an app that gives access to native phone features

Wink Toolkit - http://www.winktoolkit.org/
 - like JQueryMobile in that it is a pure web app

Comment: Nice... those look interesting.  Will check em' out!

Answer (score 1):

There is also [jQTouch](http://jqtouch.com).

See [Sencha Touch or jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066167/sencha-touch-or-jquery-mobile)

Also, there is a nice explanation what is a mobile web-app and a native application and what category these frameworks belong to: http://beautyindesign.com/blog/titanium-phonegap-sencha-touch-jquery-mobile-clearing-up-confusion/