# jqtouch doesn't do page animation on android

Tags: android, ios, jqtouch

I'm trying to create a webapp using the tutorials out there using jqtouch.  But the resulting webapps have animation on the iphone but no page transition animation on the android devices.  Can anyone tell me if there is something special I need to do to make sure that page transition/effects are animated on the android as well.

http://jqtouch.com

They claim that it supports android.  I've seen tutorials that claim that it works the same on both ios and android but I have not been able to reproduce that.

Comment: It's still in beta. Perhaps they haven't implemented animations for Android yet?

Comment: Try getting jQTouch from GitHub instead of the download from their site. The download on their site is a bit behind. https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing a non-trivial webapp (say, > 5 "pages"), I think you should check out [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) or [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/). Both of them have better support for Android and other platforms (iOS is sort of a gimme). There are several posts on SO re. this topic:

- [Sencha Touch or jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066167/sencha-touch-or-jquery-mobile)
- [What are some good Mobile Frameworks/SDKs that are web compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682647/what-are-some-good-mobile-frameworks-sdks-that-are-web-compliant)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086863/best-cross-mobile-javascript-framework-iphone-android