# Is better for mobile app Jquerymobile or Sencha Touch? (using with Phonegap)

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, sencha-touch

Which is better for mobile app development: jQuery Mobile or Sencha Touch? (using with PhoneGap)

And if Sencha, why?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: similar post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066167/sencha-touch-or-jquery-mobile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out this Quora thread.
http://www.quora.com/Were-deciding-between-jQuery-Mobile-currently-in-alpha-and-Sencha-Touch-What-are-the-pros-and-cons-for-each

Seems like public opinion is slanted towards Sencha Touch. In my startup company, we've felt the same. Started with jQuery Mobile but migrated to Sencha Touch after many problems.

Answer (score 0):

For our enterprise customers who need wide support on WebOS and Windows Phone 7, we use jQuery Mobile since it supports IE 7.

Sencha has serious issues with Android devices-- for instance, scrolling sometimes completely freezes.  It's gotten much better, but I wouldn't release a production Android app using Sencha Touch at the moment.  It works great on IOS-- my consumer iPhone app uses Sencha Touch.

Comment: have you know if those issues with Android still happening ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales been a while since I used Sencha, but in general, Android <= 4 is pretty rough w/ cordova or mobile web.  Even on Android 4, you'll want to test on an actual device and minimize/eliminate fixed-position elements b/c of scrolling performance issues.