# Sencha Touch over jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch

What is main feature of **Sencha Touch** over **jQueryMobile** I don't understand.
as per my knowledge about this two technology:


1) **jQueryMobile** have very simple data attribute feature for design app for cross mobile platform but as compare to **Sencha Touch**.


2) **Sencha Touch**  have new concept and their structure to implement designing for page is  very difficult compare to **jQuery Mobile**.

Then What is significance of **Sencha** and **jqueryMobile** and What is their own area in Which they both play role significantly ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sencha Touch or jQuery Mobile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066167/sencha-touch-or-jquery-mobile)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Intro

Unlike jQuery Mobile **`Sencha Touch`** (just like **`App Framework`**) is made specifically to work on mobile platforms and it is highly optimized. Where jQuery Mobile is made to work equally on desktop and mobile devices and it is not optimized like **`Sencha Touch`**. This is not bad for jQuery Mobile but it also means jQuery Mobile is not best solution form mobile hybrid applications.

## Good side of Sencha Touch

- It is several times faster then jQuery Mobile, you can find several benchamark articles if you google a bit. From my experience Sencha Touch mobile applications works much much smoother then jQuery Mobile ones. Again this is not an attack on jQuery Mobile, Sencha is highly optimized not to mention build to run only on web kit browsers.
- Much better application packaging system then Phonegap which is usually used with jQuery Mobile
- Did I say it is FAAAAAAST, a little bit slower then App Framework but still extremely fast.
- Excellent documentation with huge number of tutorials and video examples.

## vs. the bad

- Unlike jQuery Mobile don't expect Sencha Touch to work on a desktop browsers. First it is optimized to work on a smaller devices and it will work only on web kit browsers which makes it unusable for Firefox, IE8+ ....
- It uses complex and alien syntax, specially to someone coming from jQuery Mobile or jQuery like syntax.
- Development application is a paid app so you need to expect initial expenses.
- Don't expect native app feeling, mobile apps made with HTML5 will never have 100% native feel.
- Unlike Sencha official documentation jQuery Mobile is still much more represented on the internet

## Final advise

If Sencha Touch is not something you are willing to spend time on and jQuery Mobile is too sluggish for you, consider using **[PhoneJS](http://www.gajotres.net/in-depth-review-of-phonejs-html5-javascript-framework/)** or [**Kendo UI**](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-vs-kendo-ui/). Unlike Sencha Touch, they are built on jQuery, but unlike jQuery they are fast as Sencha Touch.

Comment: I think I got much of understanding using above tips.<br>@Gajotres I have also seen that sencha touch is not working in mozila. and also for developing app using sencha touch is very difficult without Sencha Architect and their initial cost is also high.I appreciate that. thank you once again @Gajotres

Comment: Everything is clear now, thanks Sir, you saved me a lot of time understanding which is the best for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a jQuery fork, special for mobile devices called **[Zepto.JS](http://zeptojs.com/)**. You have a lot of extra mobile events like swipe and it's a lot smaller and faster than the regular jQuery lib. Downside is that you don't have the UI elements like you have in Sencha Touch or jQuery Mobile, but you have a lot of freedom. And it's MIT licensed. I like that a lot.